# HTML not showing Angularjs's variable value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, umbraco

Im trying to show an Angularjs's variable value in HTML with the following code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyTextbox">

<p>Fecha de ultima actualizacion: {{nodeID1}} </p>
```

Here is the code for my angularjs controller:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("MyTextbox", function ($scope,$routeParams) {

$scope.nodeID1 = "Hello World";
```

});

But nothing display this way.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `ng-app="umbraco"`before `ng-controller` directive, or write it on `body`/`html` tag would be preferable.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="umbraco" ng-controller="MyTextbox">

    <p>Fecha de ultima actualizacion: {{nodeID1}} </p>

</div>
```

and your app should be

```
angular.module("umbraco",[]).controller("MyTextbox", function ($scope,$routeParams) {

     $scope.nodeID1 = "Hello World";
});
```

**Note**

> If `$routeParams` has not added mistakenly then your app would be
>   `angular.module("umbraco",['ngRoute'])` then you need to additionally add `angular-route.js`

Comment: Im sorry, im newbi ... where i need to add ng-app= "umbraco"? @pankajparkar

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

   angular.module("umbraco",[]).controller("MyTextbox", ['$scope', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.nodeID1 = "Hello World";
   }]); 

 </script>

</head>
<body >
    <h1>My Textbook</h1>
    <div ng-app="umbraco" ng-controller="MyTextbox">
      <p>Fecha de ultima actualizacion: {{nodeID1}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing happens. @Luis Menjivar

Comment: Visit [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jycryrc/2/) and hit run. Hit the developer tools and click console to see if you get any errors. Or check your server to see if you get any errors.